# How to pass queryset as single items inDdjango?

Tags: python, django, django-3.0

I have the following in my `views.py`:

`Going = Flight.objects.filter(date__gt=datetime.now()).order_by('-date')`

This fetches all flights leaving after `now`.

But, when I pass it to the template through `{{Going}}`, I get the queryset `<QuerySet [<Flight: TP450>]>` instead of the each single flight.

In my model, each flight has a `flight_ref`.

How can I pass each item so I can create a table with them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must set a loop, because you have an iterable object: Queryset. So you can use following logic in your template. About for loop in template doc [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#for)

```
{% for g in Going %}

{{ g.flight_ref}}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: @kamilryb I had just tried that and it solved my problem! Thanks anyway!

Comment: Happy  coding  :)